Error when pruning a model: model = (ckpt.get("ema") or ckpt["model"]).to(device).float() # FP32 model
I am trying to prune a YOLOv8 detection model. Following is my code and it runs successfully and I see the saved pruned model. But when I want to train it or run prediction on it, I get the following error. What is going wrong? Is my pruning process correct? I apply pruning to all layers containing cv1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\yolo.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ultralytics\cfg\__init__.py", line 555, in entrypoint
    model = YOLO(model, task=task)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ultralytics\models\yolo\model.py", line 23, in __init__
    super().__init__(model=model, task=task, verbose=verbose)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 151, in __init__
    self._load(model, task=task)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 240, in _load
    self.model, self.ckpt = attempt_load_one_weight(weights)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ultralytics\nn\tasks.py", line 792, in attempt_load_one_weight
    model = (ckpt.get("ema") or ckpt["model"]).to(device).float()  # FP32 model

And here is my pruning code:
import torch
from torch.nn.utils import prune
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load your model
model = YOLO('best.pt')
ratio=0.5

for name, module in model.named_modules():
    if "cv1.conv" in name:  # Check if the layer name contains "cv1"
        print(f"Pruning layer: {name}")
        prune.l1_unstructured(module, name='weight', amount=ratio)  # Prune the 'conv' submodule
        prune.remove(module, 'weight')  # Optional: Apply pruning permanently

# Save the pruned model
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'pruned_model.pt')

And some sample layers in my model:
...
model.model.18
model.model.18.cv1
model.model.18.cv1.conv
model.model.18.cv1.bn
model.model.18.cv2
model.model.18.cv2.conv
model.model.18.cv2.bn
...
model.model.19.conv
model.model.19.bn
model.model.20
model.model.21
...


Is it a full error log? I see the traceback but don't see the error type and description

Yeah this was all it showed me.
